# Node Highlight Disappeared after 1 second in Firebug

Tags: firebug

This problem came about recently. When I mouseover a HTML node in Firebug, it highlights the node in the page view. The highlight used to stay on the page until mouseout of the node. Now the highlight goes away after about 0.5 sec no matter what, even if my mouse stays within the node.

I was on version 24.0. The problem started just today. After googling around and try looking for setting for it all over the place, i gave up and install the 26.0 ver (latest at time of writing). I was driving nuts when I see the same problem again.

Can someone illuminate what's going on? and more importantly, how to fix it.

Curiously it only applies to Mac OS. My Windows 7 box doesn't seem to have the same problem.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but offered in a spirit of helpfulness: the correct form of the idiom would be "it was driving me nuts" -- "I was driving nuts" suggests either hitting them with a hammer, or a steering wheel down your shorts. :)